# What is the equivalent of this CSS in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div style="float:left;">
    column 1
</div>
<div style="float:left;">
    column 2
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

I'm used to writing `clear:both`.  But I heard in Twitter Bootstrap there is something called "clearfix"? On which element should/would I apply "clearfix"?

Comment: I have no idea about Twitter Bootstrap, but every `.clearfix` implementation I've seen applies exactly what you're doing now. It would just be `<div class="clearfix"></div>` instead.

Comment: I've been wondering about this. Personally, I think it is an _intentional_ omission. :) A suggestion that whether a div clears floats or not is not a concern of the markup, but of the class. For example, a navbar-inner clears. You can use the Bootstrap mixin .clearfix() to make a widget clear. But this is just a guess, which is why I don't want to make it an answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using css you can simple use the after psudeo

```
.class1:after, .class2:after //append as many as you like
{
 clear:both;
 *zoom:1;
 height:0;
 visibility: hidden;
 display:block;
}

alternative(providing children are not using the position selector)
(parent-elemts){overflow:hidden;}//bit of a quick fix!
```

keep unwanted markup out of your html file

Edit: sorry! for some reason the add comment button or upvote button is not working for me tonight.

To append my answer to answer your other question:

twitter bootstrap you say uses a .clearfix class, which is similar to the css I provided below, however their method needs to be added to the element, ie: "element class="clearfix" OR similar, where as css pseduo's we dont need to add this extra bit of code to our document.  Take note however, not all browsers support css pseduo's.

Answer (score 10):

You probably only have to do:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="span6">column 1</div>
      <div class="span6">column 2</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

`clearfix` should not be necessary.

Comment: Close, but the `clearfix` class needs to go on `div.container`. It is necessary to properly clear any `div`s following `div.container`.

Comment: @MichaelIrwin I'm not completely convinced that's necessary, but my experience with Bootstrap is not extensive at this point.

Comment: Note that I've updated this answer to account for Twitter Bootstrap's change to 12 columns and to correct my answer.